# Finding the minimum number of subrectangles in a binary array

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to program an algorithm to find the minimum number of rectangles needed to cover every "1" in a randomly generated binary 0 and 1 matrix. I've found some information online, but there are a few caveats with this specific problem that have me stumped.

1. Each group should contain the largest number of 'ones' and no blank cells.
2. The number of 'ones' in a group must be a power of 2 i.e. a group can contain: 16, 8, 4, 2, or 1 'ones'
3. Grouping is carried-on in decreasing order meaning, one has to try to group for 8 (octet) first,
   then for 4 (quad), followed by 2 and lastly for 1 (isolated 'ones').
4. Grouping is done either horizontally or vertically or in terms of rectangles/squares. Diagonal
   grouping of 'ones' is not permitted.
5. The same element(s) may repeat in multiple groups only if this increases the size of the group.
6. The elements around the edges of the matrix, including the four corners, are considered to be
   adjacent and can be grouped together.

I haven't had any issues generating the matrix. And I've read other sources on algorithms to find the biggest subrectangle in a matrix, but not all of them and especially not if you include overlaps. My biggest problem is figuring out the last requirement, and how I would express the outer edges being adjacent algorithmically.

Comment: Something similar to K-Map grouping?

Comment: Seems like that's exactly what it is, although I had no idea it was called that.

Comment: @Dlent Could you please add some examples with different scenarios for better understanding of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Once I learned the actual term for this type of problem, Karnough Map, I was able to look up other resources on it. Thanks, Mathur.

I used this website as a reference specifically for c++ implementation.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649849/A-Cplusplus-Karnaugh-Map-Minimizer-Infinite-Variab